# Roots of a quadratic equation modulo p

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

Suppose that $f(x)$ is a quadratic monic polynomial in $x$ with integer coefficients; for instance, 
$$ f(x) = x^2 + 3 x + 7.$$

Using quadratic reciprocity, it is easy to find necessary and sufficient congruence conditions on a prime $p$ such that $f(x)$ has either (1) no root or (2) two unequal roots modulo $p$. (There can be a multiple root for only finitely many $p$, which we ignore for the moment.)

Now suppose $p$ is such that (2) holds, and let $u_1, u_2$ denote the roots. Can we give necessary and sufficient conditions on $p$ which distinguish between the following cases?

(A) The Legendre symbols $(u_1/p)$ and $(u_2/p)$ are both $1$. 
(B) They are both $-1$. 
(C) One of them is $1$ and the other is $-1$.

Comment: I’m not sure the character mod $p$ of $u_1$ and $u_2$ is significant. Rather, it’s the character of the discriminant, which clearly must be $+1$. But when you add a constant to the square roots of the discriminant, I would not expect that you can say anything interesting about the character of the result. (I’ll love to be proved wrong on this, though!)

Comment: why not solving it, and check if the two roots are both 1 or both -1 or one of them is 1 and the other is -1

Comment: i think it can't be the third (C) case ever.